# How to style an Horizontal Splitter panel in GWT 1.5

Tags: html, css, gwt, stylesheet

I have this requirement to style a right side of a horizontal splitter panel. From what i know, GWT 1.7 has support for the individual panel (left and right) styles, But we are using GWT 1.5 here.

gwt code:

```
HTML div1 = new HTML("Div 1");
div1.setWidth("200px");
div1.setHeight("200px");
HTML div2 = new HTML("Div 2");
div2.setWidth("400px");
div2.setHeight("500px");

HorizontalSplitPanel horizontalSPanel = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
horizontalSPanel.setLeftWidget(div1);
horizontalSPanel.setRightWidget(div2);

RootPanel.get().add(horizontalSPanel);
```

corresponding output:

```
<div class="gwt-HorizontalSplitPanel" style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
    <div style="border: medium none ; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div style="border: medium none ; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; overflow: auto; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 511px;">
            <div class="gwt-HTML" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">Div 1</div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 511px;">
            <table height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="hsplitter">
            <tbody>
                <tr><td valign="middle" align="center">
                    <img border="0" style="background: transparent url(http://localhost:8888/com.xyzpackage.MyEntryPoint/4BF90CCB5E6B04D22EF1776E8EBF09F8.cache.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px; width: 7px; height: 7px; -moz-background-clip: -moz-initial; -moz-background-origin: -moz-initial; -moz-background-inline-policy: -moz-initial;" src="http://localhost:8888/com.xyzpackage.MyEntryPoint/clear.cache.gif"/>
                </td></tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="border: medium none ; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; overflow: auto; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 518px;">
            <div class="gwt-HTML" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;">Div 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there any way in which i can apply a style only to the RHS div ?

basically, I got a requirement which does not permit my application to have a vertical scrollbar in the RHS view.

Comment: GWT 2.0 is out. I'd advise updating.

Comment: :) thats not my call, our application is huge.

Comment: actually my requirement is Wierd, there is an element in RHS that should be "always on top" ie, the rest elements should be scrollable. However, our requirement also does not allow double scroll bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to resort to DOM:

```
                Node node = horizontalSPanel.getElement().getFirstChildElement().getChildNodes().getItem(2);
                // set the overflow y to hidden, this is in point of view of GWT current version
                // does not allow user to set style to right or left containers. 
                DOM.setStyleAttribute((Element) node, "overflowY", "hidden");
```

This is very lame and uses hard coding

Any one having a better solution ??

Answer (score 3):

You can always wrap the Div 2 into another Div and give this one the overflowY:hidden attribute, so you don't need to go through the DOM tree.

Is the same approach used in ScrollPanel only for the opposite reason.

Comment: The problem is scrollbars, see this "Scroll bars inside or outside of box?" in this page
http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

one browser counts it, another does not, thus setting 100% width and height has different behaviour and firefox shows double scrollbars.